# problem when uploading an image with mega api in python

Tags: python-3.x, file-upload

I used mega API in python to upload a text file and it worked fine but with images it always fail and gave me this error:

> requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
> HTTPConnectionPool(host='gfs204n104.userstorage.mega.co.nz', port=80):
> Read timed out. (read timeout=160)

The code I used to do that:

```
print("manga not found")
    #if the manga doesn't exist 
    #check if the upload type is manga or chapter
    if upload_type == "manga":
        #add a new manga and upload it's info
        print("start upload")
        #manga_info = login.upload(data[2])
        #info_link = login.export(manga_name + '.txt')
        #print(info_link)
        manga_thumb = login.upload(data[3])
        thumb_link = login.export(os.path.basename(data[3]))
        print(thumb_link)
        sheet.append_row([manga_name, thumb_link])
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?